# Which is the best way to retrieve data and add them to a database?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, data-retrieval

Let's say I want to retrieve data from a static web page. When retrieved I want to add them to my existing database.

Which is the best way to do it? Until now I thought of creating a Java app to retrieve the needed data and create an Excel file to add them. Afterwards I can import this file. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Whey use an Excel file to do this? It's an unnecessary extra step. And why is the question tagged PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Well in PHP, I'd create a function to read the data from the page url
break the data apart and insert into the database accordingly.

Data mining or data extraction.